# How to equate the limit definition of almost sure convergence to the limit infimum epsilon definition?

Tags: probability

The following is a definition of almost sure convergence:

$$
\mathbb P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\right\} \right)=1
$$

I have seen it written equivalent to

$$
\mathbb P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\liminf_{n\to\infty} |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|<\varepsilon \right\}\right)=1, \text{ for all }\varepsilon > 0
$$

but do not know why. Is there a reason for this and how can I think about it intuitively? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one direction is true as @geetha290krm has mentioned a counter-example for the other direction. Having said that, notice that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n}(\omega) = X(\omega) & \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}(X_{n}(\omega) - X(\omega)) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}|X_{n}(\omega) - X(\omega)| = 0
\end{align*}

Since the limit of a sequence of real numbers exists iff the $\liminf = \lim = \limsup$, it results that
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{n\to\infty}|X_{n}(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
for every $\varepsilon > 0$.

Consequently, due to the monotonicity of the probability measure, one gets the desired result:
\begin{align*}
1 = \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n}(\omega) = X(\omega)\right\}\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \liminf_{n\to\infty}|X_{n}(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon\right\}\right) \leq 1
\end{align*}
since the proposed relation holds for every $\varepsilon > 0$, and we are done.

Comment: OP is asking for equivalence, not just one way implication.

Comment: @geetha290krm Should I keep my answer though?

Comment: Now that you have added a comment in  the beginning of your answer, you can keep it.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia How is monotonicity being applied above? If I understand correctly, the inequality results from the set on the left being a subset of the set on the right. But why is it that $\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n}(\omega) = X(\omega)\right\} \subseteq \left\{\omega\in\Omega : \liminf_{n\to\infty}|X_{n}(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon\right\}$?

Comment: @user321627 That is because we have proven that the convergence of the sequence implies the convergence of the $\liminf$ of the same sequence, which corresponds to the inclusion relation you have noticed.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia Thanks, if the sequence converges iff the lim inf converges as well, why did we use the inequality instead of equality? In other words, it seems that $\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n}(\omega) = X(\omega)\right\} = \left\{\omega\in\Omega : \liminf_{n\to\infty}|X_{n}(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon\right\}$, and so is the inequality generally always an equality?

Comment: @user321627 The pointwise convergence of the sequence $X_{n}$ implies the pointwise convergence of the $\liminf$, but the converse is not true in general. There are sequences whose $\liminf$ exists and is finite, but the sequence does not convergence. Take into account the example given by geetha290krm.

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Counter-example: $X_n=1$ for $n$ even , $0$ for $n$ odd and $X=0$.